# Can I fire a View in GA4 when a <img> is loaded?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Our company has a job application site. Once a user begins an application, they are directed to a separate platform. You cannot use JS nor iFrames within the secondary platform. For our previous UA instance, I was able to trigger a pageview on the application confirmation page, when an image tag was loaded. From this, we were able to measure roughly how many applications were submitted. The tag was structured like this:

```
 <img border="0" height="1" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&amp;t=pageview&amp;tid=UA-XXXXXXX-3&amp;cid=xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx&amp;ec=Forms&amp;ea=Complete%20Application&amp;el=Complete%20Application&amp;dp=%252Fthank-you&amp;dt=Application%20Submitted%20-%20Thanks" width="1" />
```

I believe that I constructed this tag using https://ga-dev-tools.google/hit-builder/. However, GA4 has changed this (https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/event-builder/). I'm not sure how to use Event Builder to create a similar event. Obviously, json format is being used, and I'm not sure if it's possible to translate that into url format, nor how to do it, if it is possible.

Any guidance would be appreciated.